# How to navigate with moving people or objects

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, pioneer, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now i have working a pioneer dx3 with navigation and gmapping.  The robot learns dynamically from gmapping and navigates the environment.  But i need to navigate with moving people in the environment and I dont know how to accomplish it.  Ive seen that eband_local_planner works, but as the person moves the path the person just walks is marked as obstacle.  So i need to be able to have an environment of moving people and clear the path they walk.  Any ideas will be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91961/how-to-navigate-with-moving-people-or-objects./) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider joining the navigationSIG and discuss there:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-navigation

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0